# Use value of node output for driver

Tags: node-editor, drivers, path

Situation: I have an Object that rotates (keyframed). I use Nodes and Drivers to set the objects color to blue within the first quarter of one whole rotation (90°) and red for the rest (270°).
That is working fine.

Now I want to use this Color Output (blue or red/0 or 1) to drive another objects keyframe.

I need a way to get these colors as a value which I can use as a single property in the drivers menu. But I can't seem to get any working data paths from the nodes to fit into the "path: slot" in the drivers panel.

Comment: why not use the same rotation itself to drive the other object since the color depends on the rotation

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't really possible AFAIK, as node outputs are calculated by the render engine at render time. Instead you can use the object's rotation as Chebhou suggests.