# get output value as driver

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

Is there any way to get the result of the Divide node as a driver?

Comment: Hi :) As [commented here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/27904/78972) by @gandalf3 and [also here on devtalk](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/is-it-possible-to-read-the-output-values-of-nodes-from-a-material/7899) this isn't possible since node outputs are calculated at rendertime

Comment: I posted a solution here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/265349/436