# Passing GeoNodes attribute to Shader frame offset

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes, geometry

I am trying to pass a geometry nodes output attribute (an integer) to the shader editor to control the offset of an image sequence.
I have succesfully done this to pass the attribute and change , ie: the color in the shader.
But, As the image sequence offset does not have an input...
I have tried to do so using Drivers... but I am missing something about how to pass the attribute to the frame offset
I havent found any answer searching..
any help?
regards
[image]

Comment: I have managed to pass the value of the output from the Group Output (an integer) by copying the Drivers and pasting in the shader editor (bpy.data.node_groups['Geometry Nodes'].nodes['Group Output'].inputs[2].default_value ). BUT, this only udates the value if I change the value manually in the within geonodes. If I plug the valur to another integer socket that changes , then it does not update.... ¿Why?

Comment: Image sequence offset is the same for all shader pixels, you cannot use a different image for different parts of the surface (that's why the value is not a socket). If you need that, a better option would be an image atlas and offsetting UVs.
If you just want a single image and drive the offset with GN, you could encode the value in a vertex position, use an Empty with a location constraint, add a vertex group to make it follow a single vertex. The Empty location can then be the input for a driver in your shader node, extracting the offset value again. Convoluted but it works.

Comment: I just want to change the whole image for the whole object using the sequence. What I dont understand, is why it works if I insert by hand the FRAMES value in the group output, and it does not work if I use an integer node or any other variable node.

Comment: When you read the value from the group output node it's a fixed number in the node tree, whereas the geometry nodes output is a (temporary) mesh. You can't get the result of the nodes math from the node tree itself. It's like the difference between reading source code and actually executing that code.

I'll see if i can make a quick example for using the node result in a driver ...

Comment: Ah.. curious.... so.. how to pass a value? I have tested a similar setup to pass the color and a material to the saher and it works....  difficult to get the concept. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

How to expose geometry nodes result as driver inputs:

[image]

1. Compute some value in geometry nodes. In this case it's going to be a frame offset, so I calculate some integer number.
2. The mesh only has a single vertex. You could output multiple values in different vertices, but for simplicity I'll stick to 1 vertex only.
   [image]
3. Add the mesh vertex to a Vertex Group.
4. Add an *Empty* object. This will be the thing that the driver can actually use.
5. Add a *Copy Location* constraint to the Empty. Set the single-vertex-mesh as target and the vertex group. Now the Empty will follow the position of our single vertex, which in turn encodes the frame value we want to output.
   [image]
6. Finally add a driver to the image sequence node as before. Use the Empty object's X position as the driver variable. Now you can change the values in geometry nodes, the Empty will follow the vertex position, and the driver will change the sequence offset accordingly.
   [image]

Comment: Thank you. I willstudy this setup and try with mine. Thanks