# Geometry Nodes output attribute as a driver for another object. How to make it work?

Tags: geometry-nodes, drivers

Using Geometry Nodes I know that I can sample a curve and move an object along this curve. However, this approach doesn't affect children of the object moving along the curve.

For this purpose I wanted to use geometry nodes output attributes as a driver for my object that I want to move along the curve.

[image]

Now say I want to use _X attribute as a driver. Is this possible? I'm copying data path e.g. for _X and it looks as follows:

modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Output_2_attribute_name"]

But when I try to use it in a Driver I get always zero. What do I miss?

[image]

Comment: Ok. Seems like I ll try this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/265282/passing-geonodes-attribute-to-shader-frame-offset/265349#265349

Comment: Hi, Fedor,  I suspect your link is the best way at the moment, so this question can be closed as a duplicate.  If you disagree / it doesn't work, go ahead and edit the post, explaining why, and we can re-open it for you.