# Can the output attribute of the Geometry Nodes modifier be used as a driver?

Tags: animation, node-editor, drivers

How to make the output attribute of the Geometry Nodes modifier control other object attributes, such as the spot size of a spotlight, if it can be used as a driver?

I worked out the number, but I can't seem to write it into the properties of the light.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing GeoNodes attribute to Shader frame offset](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/265282/passing-geonodes-attribute-to-shader-frame-offset)

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I think the question is not about GN > Shader, but about GN > Light properties (which to my knowledge is not possible).

Comment: @quellenform the GN > Shader uses a driver driven by an empty hooked to a vertex controlled by GN. Light Properties could be likewise driven by an empty hooked to a vertex controlled by GN.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Ah, cool, right, that would be possible. I was thinking of direct control.

Comment: @Markus von Broady Thanks for your reply! I tried it, as if to change the empty object by copying the position. It moved, but the number of the position attribute did not change. I also tried to bind the parent, but it didn't work.

Comment: @Markus von Broady I tried again. It seems that even if the value of the position attribute of the empty object has not changed, it can still have an effect, but I found that if the geometric node merges geometry when it is finally output, it will fail, because my geometric node is not only used to drive and control the vertices of the empty object, but also to do other grid effects. Maybe I should transfer the data to another new geometric node to control the empty object?

Comment: @F91 sounds reasonable, a separate object I'd call a "geo-driver bridge", that accesses the data in the geometry of other objects and applies it as position of its vertices (which aren't dynamically created, so that hooking empties to them works).

Comment: @Markus von Broady I found that the original vertex group data will be lost if other geometric data are added to the join geometric nodes to merge and output, which may be the original.