# How can I add a Vertex to the end of a trim curve node in geometry nodes to track a camera off?

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, tracking

I'm using geometry nodes to set up a dripping ink effect using trim curve and I'd like to add a Vertex to the end of the trim curve to track a camera off.

[image: trim curve]

[image]

Comment: "track a camera off" = ? As for adding a vertex, spawn a single vertex (e.g. grid of resolution 1×1) and set position, with the sampled factor `0` or `1` of the curve after it has been trimmed.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not being clear. I'd like to add a vertex to the end of the trim curve, and use the 'track-to' constraint on the camera to follow the drip (end of the curve).

Comment: Use this answer to create an empty and track the camera to the empty: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/265349/60486

Comment: Okay I'm not sure I totally understand how to do this I'm fairly new to the software. Thanks very much for your help.