# An equivalent of "Sample Curve" but in a driver expression?

Tags: drivers

I would like to utilize a curve tangent or a curve normal in my driver (i.e. in its Scripted expression)
When working with geometry there's the "Sample Curve" node for that. Is it possible to obtain those values in a property driver?

**What I am trying to do:**

1. have my vehicle model follow a path object
   Done - I used the "Follow path" constraint on the vehicle parent object.
2. have the wheels rotate according to the distance travelled along this path object
   Done - a driver on the "Rotation X" in Delta Transform does that for me. (The driver references the offset of the aforementioned "Follow Path" constraint.)
3. have the wheels steer/aim according to the tangent (or the normal?) of the curve

Comment: You could use this technique: [Passing GeoNodes attribute to Shader frame offset](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/265282/60486) to read the data in geonodes and pass it to a driver.

Comment: The cleanest method might well be case-by-case .. could you give an example of _how_ you want to use the vectors?

Comment: @RobinBetts good point, I am going to update the question elaborate more

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Thanks, that's a step in the right direction! I am not very skilled in Blender, so I don't know yet how to bring the tangent at a point on a path object into the "calculation" part of another object... While the point is determined by a constraint: ${constraints["Follow Path"].offset}

Answer (score 1):

Only now I realized I can add inputs to my Geometry Node group, and such input can have its own driver:
[image]