# Geometry nodes how to capture the position of a point and use this position in a seperate node set up

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, camera, instances, custom-attributes

This is a simplified version of what I'm after.
I have two "distribute points on faces" nodes, one instances the Cones and the other instances the Torus. (There is a node group that limits the torus to only 1 Torus at a time)

[image]

How would you capture the position of the torus and use this position data in a different geometry node set up to position a curve line on the exact point of the torus?

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, just have a separate object with a single vertex, and use geonodes there to position that vertex based on the logic you need.You can also set the position of the 2nd vertex to some other data you want to output like rotation. Hook empties to those vertices, and use parenting, drivers, constraint, whatever you need. [Passing GeoNodes attribute to Shader frame offset](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/265282/60486) - see also linked threads on the right column.

Comment: Is your core issue about extracting a location from a geometry node and then utilizing it in another geometry node?

Comment: Yes, That's it. I assume it's solved using attributes, but I can't figure out how it's done.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two geometry nodes, let's call them geo1 and geo2, you can utilize 'object info' within geo2 to import data from the geo1 geometry node. This way, you can use the Index number to access any data within geo1, including the positional information you need.
[image]
[image]

Comment: That doesn't work with the distribution point of faces. If I use this method on my node set up the Ico sphere positions itself around the plane objects vertices. How would I get the Ico sphere to position itself on the torus object's position?

Comment: If you are trying to obtain the location of an instance, you should select 'instance' in the 'sample index' node. Then, you need to figure out the index of that instance.