# How to make a driver from a value resulting of calculation in geometry nodes, to drive a parameter in a shader?

Tags: geometry-nodes, drivers, mathematics

In geometry node, I made a quick setup to calcul the distance between my geometry and the camera. I'd like to get the result of this calculation to make a driver, for driving a scale maping parameter of a shader for exemple.
How can I get the "result"? Is there a way to display the result as numbers and copy it as new driver?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing GeoNodes attribute to Shader frame offset](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/265282/passing-geonodes-attribute-to-shader-frame-offset)

Comment: Thank you, yes, but a very complex solution from my point of view. This kind of thing is done in 2 clicks with houdini

Comment: There isn't a 2-click solution, unfortunately.

Comment: At first sight, it doesn't look as if you need a driver, just write the camera-proximity as an attribute, read it, and do all the math in the shader? (Actually, you could get camera-proximity entirely in the shader and not use GN at all) Am I missing something?

Comment: You're right, but I was wondering if my solution could be possible, I find it more simple for optimisation , one place to control many things... But I think the camera proximity in shader graph give the proximity  with the shader and not with the object, am I right?

Comment: You can use `Attribute` node in `object` mode and `location` name to get the object's location inside the shader.